# String encryption and decryption in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I need help to encrypt the string and return encrypted result in the form of binary like (eg. 10101111101). And also need help to decrypt the binary result back. please guide me.

i used this piece of code.. 
it encrypt/decrypt of string works perfectly. but the problem is that the encrypted result contains "Special character, operators etc"
i do not want this. I need  encrypted result will be "alphanumeric,numeric,binary,alphabetic" only

```
function encryptIt( $q ) {
$cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
$qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
return( $qEncoded );}


function decryptIt( $q ) {
$cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
$qDecoded      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
return( $qDecoded );}
```

Comment: why you all people gave me a minus point.. i need only help.. just please guide me.

Comment: You got the minus-points for not providing anything. We would love to help you, but we don't do your homework (or similar). Provide examples. What have you tried so far?

Comment: ok wait a moment i will update my question

Comment: @DasSaffe please have a look on my code and give me suggestions and guide line

Comment: The encrypted string (`$qEncoded`) is the 'encrypted string', which is the result of the encryption (a binary string), that is then encoded as 'base64'. So is safe to be used almost everywhere. When you decrypt it you will get, if the password is correct, the original string back or some binary rubbish string ;-/

Comment: i use this for url.. { echo $url_string = urlencode( base64_encode ($encrypt)); }

Comment: if you want see `$qDecoded` in a safe form, such as hex, then use `bin2hex` on the returned result.

Comment: yup i think i am going on right direction ... :D

Comment: thanks all of you.. sorry for non professional question. I am new on stack overflow. This question spoil my reputation.. But next time i will ask question  if needed after my own research. Thanks @RyanVincent

Comment: Don't use these functions. They're NOT secure.

Comment: @HamzaHafeez Where did you copy these functions from? Please go to the source and tell them their code is insecure, and switch to [a secure encryption library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) instead.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski what ever i use it just for assignment..

Comment: @HamzaHafeez That's the sort of attitude that leads to the development of shoddy software that brings multimillion companies to the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to solve this is to covert the ciphertext to and from hex after encryption and before decryption.

Code:

```
$string = "10101111101";
$encrypted = encryptIt($string);
$decrypted = decryptIt($encrypted);

// Change \n to <br> for newline in web browser
echo $string."\n";
echo $encrypted."\n";
echo $decrypted."\n";

function encryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qEncoded = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
    $qEncoded = strToHex( $qEncoded );
    return( $qEncoded );
}

function decryptIt( $q ) {
    $q = hexToStr( $q );
    $cryptKey = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qDecoded = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
    return( $qDecoded );
}

function strToHex($string) {
    $hex = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
        $ord = ord($string[$i]);
        $hexCode = dechex($ord);
        $hex .= substr('0'.$hexCode, -2);
    }
    return strToUpper($hex);
}

function hexToStr($hex) {
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Output:

```
10101111101
62554A5951644A4B7552564C52396A69686A5A6F4A453539534850517A533573583331316D5372676C6B493D
10101111101
```

Comment: your answer marked as correct :)